# Java get line from text file, create new text file and insert

Tags: java

In my code I have this GUI animation and I want to make the animation function for its creation more generic by automatically create a new text file..

```
String getGUI = "res/worldSaves/GUI_Frames_List.txt";
String writeGUI = "res/worldSaves/GUI_Cancel_Object.txt";

private void getGUISymbol(String getGUIFrame)
{
    try
    {   
        ProcessCoords get = new ProcessCoords(getGUI);
        String[] getaryLines = get.OpenFile();

        ProcessCoords data = new ProcessCoords(writeGUI);

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < getaryLines.length; i++)
        {               
             if(getaryLines[i].startsWith(getGUIFrame))
             { 
                System.out.println("current = " + getaryLines[i]); 
                data.writeToFile("GUI"+getaryLines[i]); // this needs to generate a new text file - how?
             }
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
}
```

At the moment I have two text files, one contains a  list of all GUI Icons and the other always only the one that should currently be displayed.

My goal would be to make the program create the text file (GUI_Cancel_Object.txt) by itself at the apropriate directory and overwrite the text file each time the method is being called.

I tried to do it with PrintWriter but it didn't generate a text file, maybe my implementation was wrong - any suggestions?

Note: Process Coords is just standart Java class Methods with FileReader and such..

EDIT: The created file (in this case GUI_Cancel_Object.txt) can behave like a temporary file - gets deleted when the program shuts down.

Update:

```
    public void writeToFile(String textLine) throws IOException
    {
        FileWriter write = new FileWriter(path, append_to_file);
        PrintWriter print_line = new PrintWriter(write);

        print_line.printf("%s" + "%n", textLine);
        print_line.close();
    }
```

Comment: What does your `ProcessCoords.writeToFile()` method look like?

Comment: I've updated my answer, it's in there now.. when I delete the GUI_Cancel_Object.txt file it still works, I was expecting to see the text file in my worldSaves folder but it doesn't appear.. that's why I was confused..

Comment: yea.. still doesn't work properly, the file should appear, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should generate the file, unless there was an exception of some kind. E.g. you don't have permission to write/create files in the current working directory.
As a side note, whenever you are doing IO, it is a good idea to use try-with-resources construct to ensure close() is always invoked, e.g.

```
try (FileWriter write = new FileWriter(path, append_to_file);PrintWriter print_line = new PrintWriter(write)) {
    print_line.printf("%s" + "%n", textLine);
}
```

To create a temp file pass for example File.createTempFile(path, "txt") instead of just path to the FileWriter constructor

Comment: Oh that's interesting.. the writeToFile method from ProcessCoords is exactly this, I've now deleted the GUI_Cancel_Object.txt file and it worked properly.. I was just expecting to see the text file in the worldSaves folder once it has been created but it doesn't appear anywhere.. is that how it should be?

Comment: No wait.. I don't get it, it still doesn't work as it should.. thanks for you answer, there has to be a bug in my code I guess..

Comment: okay it works now.. the file is being created it's just that eclipse is not displaying it.. everything fine - thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, I think you need to hit F5 on the workspace to refresh file system changes in Eclipse

Comment: Thanks, refreshing didn't change anything - don't know why, but it works, that's the important thing :)